# Can you integrate a quadratic raised to an arbitrary integer power?

Tags: integration

I would like to integrate:
$\int_0^\infty (ax^2 + bx + c)^n dx$, where $n$ is a negative integer.
Does anyone know a method to do this?

My obvious first try has been using Mathematica, but it doesn't find a solution. And, I've not found it by going through Abramowitz and Stegun (although I may have missed a similar solution).

Comment: A change of variables could go in one of two ways... either as the solutions of $ax^2+bx+c$, or as $u=ax^2+bx+c$, $du=2axdx+bdx$ and replace.  Of course, the integration over $[0, \infty)$ of a quadratic (for positive $n$) will always be $\pm\infty$, so the actual integration may be moot...

Comment: It will exist if $n<-1/2$. Partial fractions may help if $n$ is an integer.

Comment: @Michael: true, but I'm assuming that you mean $n \le -1$ given that $n\in \mathbb Z-\{0\}$.

Comment: In fact in my real problem it will always be the case that $n < 1$.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere!  Just put that info plus what you have tried in your question statement and we'll be able to help you properly.  :-)

Comment: @abiessu Thanks :)

Comment: It is basic calculus. There are unfortunately several cases. The integral will not exist if the quadratic has a root $\ge 0$. If there is no root, complete the square and use a Reduction Formula. Since the calculation by hand is straightforward, Mathematica must know.

Answer (score 1):

Use simple fractions:
$$
\frac{1}{(ax^2+bx+c)^n}=\frac{1}{a^n}\frac{1}{(x-x_1)^n(x-x_2)^n}=\frac{1}{a^n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{A_k}{(x-x_1)^k} + \frac{B_k}{(x-x_2)^k}
$$